# Code Blocks compilation error

Tags: c, error-handling, codeblocks

Whenever I am trying to build and run a program the second time this error is coming on the screen:

> cannot open output file C:\Users\Username\Documents\filename.exe Permission denied

Comment: End the executable's process.

Answer (score 2):

You either 1. don't have permissions to write to the directory(unlikely)
        or 2. Your executable is still in the memory. Hit CTRL+ALT+DEL select `Windows Task Manager` and Find+End your executable "filename.exe".

Answer (score 0):

It means `The directory your code is in doesn't have write permission`. But try moving your code in some write permitted directory. BTW in my windows this problem occurs sometimes. Then when I restart codeblocks it disappears - I am not telling this is a solution.